# ¿Como puedo sumar los numero que estan en precio unitario en un formulario dinamico?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, funciones

## DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS

```
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
   <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">Nueva</div>
 </label>
 <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
  <tr>
    <th>Detalles De Insumos</th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Valor Total ($)</th>
    <th>OPCION</th>
  </tr>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($tabla1); ++$i) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_insumo[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" value=""></td>
    <td class="text-center">

     <div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div>

   </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor ? , Si envía un parámetro de tipo `GET` de la forma `php?id=valor` accediendo a `$_GET['id'];` obtendrá el valor respectivo. podría tener algo así en lugar de un botón ya con `CSS`  podría dar el estilo  de un botón.

Comment: Todo lo que quieras tener de la presente página en el archivo `Conexion_Solicitud_Pedido.php` debes enviarlo en la variable `data` que le pasas a la petición Ajax. Si quieres pasarle el valor del botón, tienes que incluirlo aquí: `data:{"param1":"dame","limit":itemsPorPagina,"offset":desde, "boton":btnValor}` suponiendo que recoges el valor del botón en la variable `btnValor`. Luego lo recuperas en el PHP mediante `$_GET` o `$_POST`, por ejemplo: `$boton=$_POST["boton"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El boton que dices es el de modificar?
en todos los casos si es asi, debes tener la funcion abrir() en algun lado que tenga un window.assign? con solo pasar el valor que queres como parametro de la funcion y tomarlo dentro de la funcion para enviarlo como GET ya deberias solucionarlo.

```
function abrir(param){
windows.location.assign("laotrapagina.php?valor="+param);
}
```

laotrapagina.php

```
<?php
$valorGET=$_GET["valor"];
?>
```

maso menos es la idea?

saludos,

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65816/discussion-on-answer-by-sebastian-mi-duda-es-que-tengo-un-boton-en-una-tabla-que).

Comment: Sebastian, gracias por tu ayuda, al final logre arreglarlo, era tema de comilla. Saludos

Comment: no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta asi se cierra